# Understanding scipy b-spline base interval

Tags: scipy, bspline

I want to use [scipy's b splines](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.BSpline.html). However, in their examples they say that compared to the naive implementation, "outside of the base interval results differ". I don't understand what the base interval here is. I need the behavior of the naive implementation, e.g. going to 0 for x going to plus/minus infinity. Is this possible to get with the scipy implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use `extrapolate=False` and replace nans with zeros.

Comment: This unfortunately doesnt work, the scipy B splines don't go smooth to 0, the "naive" implementation does though.

Comment: Please give a minimal self-contained example.